# Java: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenide

I'm trying to click an element on payment pop-up:

```
<label data-v-533987c6="" xpath="1">Card Number:</label>
<input data-v-533987c6="" type="tel" data-mask="#### #### #### ####" data-previous-value="" xpath="1">
```

with following xPath:

```java
@FindBy(name = "//div[contains(@class,'buy-tickets')]//div/label[text()='Card Number:']/following-sibling::input")
```

but I receive this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-VQ56FMV', ip: '192.168.0.13', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 80.0.3987.87, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Nastya\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64958}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 3ca3f388f2b3cf47642733a6f03...}
Session ID: 3ca3f388f2b3cf47642733a6f0383c1e
*** Element info: {Using=name, value=//div[contains(@class,'buy-tickets')]//div/label[text()='Card Number:']/following-sibling::input}
```

Why? Hope, you can help me!

Comment: The selector that is causing the issue is not the one you posted, but the one the message reports on the last line ( //div[contains(@class,'buy-tickets')]//div/label[text()='Card Number:']/following-sibling::input} )

Can you confirm that you are in fact using code that extracts using XPath, and not using CSS Selectors?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be close. Though you have mentioned the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as `By.name` in your code, but the value which you have passed:

```
//label[text()='Expiration Date:']//following::input[@type='tel'][1]
```

resembles a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath). So instead of using `By.name` you need to use **`By.xpath`** and you can use either of the following solutions:

- *xpath 1* using *following*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Card Number:']//following::input[1]"))
  ```
- *xpath 2* using *following-sibling*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Card Number:']//following-sibling::input[1]"))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message

```
Element info: {Using=name, value=//div[contains(@class,'buy-tickets')]//div/label[text()='Card Number:']/following-sibling::input}
```

you are trying to use another `xpath`

```
//div[contains(@class,'buy-tickets')]//div/label[text()='Card Number:']/following-sibling::input`
```

with `By.name`, which is invalid. You need to use `By.xpath`.

Comment: Guys, you are the best!! Thank you so much!:)

Answer (score 0):

Error message is explaining itself

> *** Element info: {Using=name, value=//div[contains(@class,'buy-tickets')]//div/label[text()='Card
>   Number:']/following-sibling::input}

You are using **xpath** but selector is using **name**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Card Number')]/following-sibling::input"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this selector is XPath
You can find an element By css, xpath, name etc
Just replace

```
@FindBy(name = "//div[contains(@class,'buy-tickets')]//div/label[text()='Card Number:']/following-sibling::input"
```

with

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'buy-tickets')]//div/label[text()='Card Number:']/following-sibling::input"
```